# Append quotes while retrieving datetime in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string column with date value as 15-07-2013 15:00.00

In my query, I want to select it as "2013-07-15 15:00.00"

Any pointers?

Comment: Do you want to concatenate the quotes as a result of an `SELECT .. SQL query`?

Comment: Yes. also i want to format in 2013-07-15 15:00.00 format. SQL 2012

Answer (score 0):

for Mysql you can use concat

```
select concat('"',date_format( STR_TO_DATE(my_column,'%d-%m-%Y %h:%i%s'), 
        '%Y-%m-%d  %h:%i%s'), '"') from my_table ;
```

for Oracle you can use ||

```
select '"' || my_column  || '"' from my_table ;
```

Comment: This does not change the format to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on MySql you can use date format function to get required format:
date_format(column_name,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')

concat double quotes, if required.

For more detail check:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

Try following using `SUBSTRING` function:

```
DECLARE @WrongFormat VARCHAR(20) = '15-07-2013 15:00.00'
SELECT  SUBSTRING(@WrongFormat, 1,  2) + '-' +
        SUBSTRING(@WrongFormat, 4,  2) +
        SUBSTRING(@WrongFormat, 6,  14)
```